# NodeEntity attributes are NULL after transaction closed when using AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, aspectj, spring-data-neo4j

I've got a strange problem when using AspectJ, Neo4j NodeEntities and transactions.

I'm developing a spring application and using spring-data-neo4j with aspectj weaving. The problem is, that my fetched entities are empty outside of the transaction. Without AspectJ everything works as expected.

Here is a full test-case with maven:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <neo4j.version>2.1.7</neo4j.version>
        <spring-data-commons.version>1.10.0.RELEASE</spring-data-commons.version>
        <spring-data-neo4j.version>3.3.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring + neo4j dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for aspectj -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>aspects</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- disable default compiler -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- enable aspectj compiler -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                                <version>1.8.5</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                                <version>1.8.5</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <outxml>true</outxml>
                            <aspectLibraries>
                                <aspectLibrary>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                                </aspectLibrary>
                                <aspectLibrary>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
                                </aspectLibrary>
                            </aspectLibraries>
                            <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**demo/DemoNode.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class DemoNode {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**demo/DemoRepository.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

public interface DemoRepository extends GraphRepository<DemoNode> {
    public DemoNode findByName(String name);
}
```

**demo/DemoApplicationTests.java**

```
package demo;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.config.Neo4jAspectConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.node.Neo4jHelper;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("demo")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "demo")
    public static class DemoConfiguration extends Neo4jAspectConfiguration {
        public DemoConfiguration() {
            setBasePackage("demo");
        }

        @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
        public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDbService;

    @Autowired
    private DemoRepository demoRepo;

    @Before
    public void resetDb() {
        Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(graphDbService);
    }

    // NOT successful
    @Test
    public void testNeo4jTransaction() {
        DemoNode node;
        final String name = "demo";

        try (Transaction tx = graphDbService.beginTx()) {
            node = new DemoNode();
            node.setName(name);

            node = demoRepo.save(node);
            tx.success();
        }
        assertEquals(name, node.getName());

        try (Transaction tx = graphDbService.beginTx()) {
            node = demoRepo.findByName(name);

            tx.success();
        }

        assertEquals(name, node.getName()); // expected:<demo> but was:<null>
    }

    // successful
    @Test
    public void testNeo4jWithGetTransaction() {
        DemoNode node;
        final String name = "demo";

        try (Transaction tx = graphDbService.beginTx()) {
            node = new DemoNode();
            node.setName(name);

            node = demoRepo.save(node);
            tx.success();
        }
        assertEquals(name, node.getName());

        try (Transaction tx = graphDbService.beginTx()) {
            node = demoRepo.findByName(name);

            tx.success();
        }

        try (Transaction tx = graphDbService.beginTx()) {
            assertEquals(name, node.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

When you test this with `mvn test` everything is fine. But when using aspectj (`mvn test -Paspects`) it will fail:
`DemoApplicationTests.testNeo4jNativeTransaction:64 expected:<demo> but was:<null>`

What I found out when debugging this: Inside the transaction with AspectJ I could retrieve the name with the getter. BUT: All properties are always `null`. So my guess is: AspectJ weaving stores the values somewhere else and overrides the setter/getter for this. The new getter requires an active transaction, so outside of the transaction it will not work/will use the default getter that doesn't work with the `null` properties.

When I'm increasing the debug level I could see some message regarding this:
`DEBUG o.s.d.n.f.DetachedEntityState - Outside of transaction, GET value from field class java.lang.String name rel: false idx: true`

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to create a clone and return this? Imho this would be an ugly way ...

Thanks in advance! I'm already searched and tried multiple hours but couldn't find any solution and any other problems here on stackoverflow or somewhere else in the internet. Maybe it's a bug ... maybe expected behaviour or maybe I'm doing some wrong ... I don't know.

**UPDATE**

I added a second test that works. It has a transaction around the getter. So when the getter is called in a transaction everything is fine. But I think this is a curious behaviour. Outside of the transaction the entity should be detached, but usable.

Comment: In general it looks ok to me, not sure what's missing. Can you try to use the node returned by demoRepo.save() instead that one would be the correct attached one not the one you created ?

Comment: `demoRepo.save()` returns the same instance than node is before. So the first test will be successful again. The second test is the one that fails. Using AspectJ at the end of `Neo4jEntityConverterImpl#read()` method it will jump out of this method after the `persistentEntity.isManaged()` check, the next method (`loadEntity`) that directly sets the entity properties will not be called. But I think this is the desired behavior. Maybe after a commit there should be something like mapping the entities content to the properties, so the normal getter will work.

Comment: Good question, I think it starts implicit transactions to read those as far as I can remember. So they should be available when read. Did you try to start a transaction around the reading?

Comment: With the transaction around the `node.getName()` it works. So the getter-call of the entity has to be in a transaction when AspectJ is used? I think this is a curious behavior. I knew that the entity is detached outside the transaction and changes will not be tracked. But I think it's very strange to use a transaction only to read properties of an already fetched entity.

Comment: Yes I wonder too, originally it worked because it opened it's own transaction for reach read (which is very inefficient). Changes are actually tracked in detached entities. it is not "fetched" there is no fetching in aspectj, it is all write-through and read-through.

Comment: Interesting approach. So with AspectJ generally ALL set/get changes are directly written to the running transaction and if there isn't any transaction a new should be opened automatically? I think in the `Neo4jNodeBacking` aspect outside of a transaction it will directly call the original getter because the `entityState` is null: `if (entity.entityState==null) return proceed(entity);`. Maybe I should open an issue in JIRA for this problem?